# Cython unsigned char uuid_t[16] representaion

Tags: c++, cython

I have structure declarations in my code:

```
cdef extern from "uuid/uuid.h":
    ctypedef unsigned char uuid_t[16]


cdef extern from "fr_common.h":
    ctypedef uuid_t fr_id_t

    ctypedef struct fr_event_t:
       fr_id_t id
       size_t action
       fr_id_t object_id
       long long ts
```

Here I have cython class where I need to pass `fr_id_t id` value from `fr_event_t` structure.

```
cdef class Event:
    cdef:
        bytes _id
        int _action
        bytes object_id
        int _ts

    def __cinit__(self, fr_id_t id, int action, fr_id_t object_id, int ts):
        self._id = id
        self._action = action
        self._object_id = object_id
        self._ts = ts
    
    @staticmethod
    cdef Event from_c(fr_event_t fr_event):
        return Event(
            fr_id_t=fr_event.id,
            action=fr_event.action,
            object_id=fr_event.object_id,
            ts=fr_event.ts,
```

How I can represent `fr_id_t` type passing it in the function somehow else? Its representation is `unsigned char uuid_t[16]` that stores bytes. Passing `fr_id_t` is not working and cython compiler gives me assertion error while compiling my .pyx file into .so.

```
AssertionError: (<FileSourceDescriptor:/home/dmitriyravdel/teyefr/teye-fr/python/teyefr/_teyefr.pyx>, 356, 24): (__pyx_v_id == ((unsigned char *)NULL)) && PyErr_Occurred()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is a bug in Cython an makes it pretty hard to diagnose. However, what you're trying to do doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

[`__init__` and `__cinit__` are fundamentally Python methods](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/special_methods.html#initialisation-methods-cinit-and-init) and their arguments must be Python objects

> All constructor arguments will be passed as Python objects. This implies that non-convertible C types such as pointers or C++ objects cannot be passed into the constructor from Cython code. If this is needed, use a factory function instead that handles the object initialisation. It often helps to directly call `__new__()` in this function to bypass the call to the `__init__()` constructor.

What will happen (if your code worked) is that first `fr_event.id` will be converted to a Python object to be passed to `__cinit__` *then* it'll be converted back to a `fr_id_t`, *then* it'll be converted to a `bytes` where you store it. **This is not what you want!** It looks like one of these conversions has confused Cython.

What you actually want to do is to create a genuinely empty `Event` in `from_c`:

```
@staticmethod
cdef from_c(fr_event_t event):
    cdef Event e = Event.__new__()  # This only works if __cinit__ is removed or takes no arguments
    e._id = event.id
    # etc
    return e
```

You also cannot have `fr_id_t` arguments to `__cinit__` since these are what triggers the issue. I'd suggest that it isn't meaningful to construct `Event` objects from Python (only Cython) so that you probably shouldn't have a `__cinit__` at all. Another alternative would be to have a `__cinit__` that takes the Python equivalent types `bytes` and `int`:

```
cdef class Event:
    cdef bytes _id
    def __cinit__(self, bytes id):
        self._id = id

    @staticmethod
    cdef from_c(fr_event_t event):
        return Event(event.id)
```

(I've cut this example down further for the sake of simplicity)

Comment: You are wrong, sir. You can pass any argument of any cython type into `__cinit__()`. E.g. __cinit__(const* char a). 
And example with dunder `__new__()` declaration aint working as you obliged to pass arguments to it.

Comment: No. `const char*` is specifically allowed because Python strings can be converted to `const char*`. Try `__cinit__(int*)` for an example that you cannot pass arbitrary C types to `__cinit__`. My `__new__()` works fine because I removed `__cinit__` (so no arguments are needed)

Comment: But using of  `__new__()` is not what I want, especially if it asks me for arguments anyway. The rest of logic with other classes is working perfect via `__cinit__()` method. The only trouble is I need to find out how to pass `unsigned char id`.

Comment: Well then why don't you try the second option I suggested where `id` is converted to `bytes` _before_ being passed to the constructor.

Comment: I tried to use the second option and eventually have got `MemoryError` after I imported package and called face recognition function which calls API C++ function that fills that structure out. Python cant read from memory or something? Do I have to implement something like memory allocation and freeing in cython?

Comment: I think that's due to [this non-bug](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3234). Your arrays probably aren't NULL-terminated and Cython assumes that they are when converting to `bytes` (hence allocates a lot more memory than needed). The solution would be to do `return Event(event.id[:16])` to set up the `bytes` properly.